# Multiple Background images different sizes

Tags: html, css

I'm building a site for a friend and currently have one background image covering the body using the following CSS:

```
body {
background: url("backgroundOriginal.jpeg") no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
height: 100%;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

he wants that photo to cover only about 25% of the page and then have either another photo or a plain white background covering the rest.

How could I do this? Would I have to get rid of the background image in the body tag and use divs instead or is there an easier way?

Comment: probably don't use body, like you said; also try different heights.

Answer (score 1):

You can make this with CSS3

```
body {
   background-image: url(images/image1.png), url(images/image2.png);
   background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat;
}
```

http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/

The current versions of the major browsers support it, however if you need to support IE8 or below, then the best way you can work around it is to have extra divs: http://caniuse.com/#search=multiple%20backgrounds

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_backgrounds.asp

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#example1 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background:url(http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/flower-png-20.png);
  background-size: 25%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding:15px;
  background-color: blue;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="example1">
<h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
<p>Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

another possibility, though it'll probably put things on the bottom.

```
-webkit-background-size: 25%;
-moz-background-size: 25%;
-o-background-size: 25%;
background-size: 25%;
```